# What's the best way to generate keywords from a given Text?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, seo

I want to generate Keywords for my CMS.

Does someone know a good PHP Script (or something else) which generates keywords?

I have a HTML Site like this: http://pastebin.com/ZU8vdyeP

Comment: "Generates" from what kind of data? Can you show an example?

Comment: People are quite good at this (;

Comment: you should let people enter the keywords , no script would match better than a human somebody has to write the content , is it that hard to enter a few more words ? . ( +1 @Harmen )

Comment: @Harmen i know :D but i'm writing a CMS for constricted people... it's not that easy for them ;)

Comment: ah , in this case please excuse my previous comment

Comment: @poelinca no problem, you didn't know ^^

Comment: But this is a very hard problem to solve... Don't tag it as php or seo, you won't get any good answers than. Rather tag it as algorithm or best-practice

Comment: @Philipp still, automatic keyword generation is usually a bad idea, as a script is unable to tell the *important* keywords apart from the *unimportant* ones. Are you sure you need keywords here in the first place? It's often enough to let the content speak for itself, give it proper `<h1><h2><h3>` tags etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very hard problem for a computer to solve. It would be much easier to get somebody (else?) to do it manually, or simply not do it at all.

If you'd really need a computer to do it, I'd head over to the excellent **Python library [NLTK](http://nltk.org/)** which has many tools for this sort of thing (=natural language processing), and it's a lot of fun to work with.

For example, you could calculate a frequency distribution of the words, and then search for the most common hypernyms of larger (above say 5 char) words that appear most frequently and use that as a hint of what the keywords could be.

Again, it is much easier to get it done by a human, however.

Answer (score 1):

to automate, get the words from the article, match them against a blacklist and dont include words under 4 chars.

Additionally, Let user manually edit. So only automate if no present keywords.

This can be done by trigger or application layer.

regards,
/t

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem, you have text and you want to determine keywords that are most relevant to the text.

Three approaches:

1) Have user enter keywords

2) Statistical analysis of text, for example determine the words that are far more common in the text than they are in the language overall.  Any good text on Information Retrieval will have some algorithms.

3) If you have a set of documents that are already classified (perhaps previously classified by humans) then you can use a machine learning algorithm (perhaps a Bayesian classifier) to train the system to classify the new documents.  If you let the users override/correct the suggested keywords, the system can learn over time.

Personally, I'd do #3, since it is more adaptive.